# log ratio from dataframe in R

Tags: r, database, extract

I have a big data frame with 5 columns and 1000+ rows like this:

```
cluster   sample_id proportion  condition patient_id
Basophils Base1001  0.358183106 Base      B1001
```

Every patient has 18 different clusters, 2 samples and 2 conditions. I have to do a log ratio of the proportion of every cluster with its match under the different condition.

I have tried to use automatic conditions like for `df$patient_id == B1001` get `cluster == Basophils` and similar things but I can't get it right.

The only thing I managed to do is subset everything and do a manual log ratio but that's too painful.

```
prueba1 = subset(ggdf, ggdf$patient_id == "B1001")
prueba2 = subset(prueba1, prueba1$cluster == "Basophils")
prueba3 = prueba2$proportion[1]/prueba2$proportion[2]
prueba4 = log(prueba3)
```

How can I do it to automatically compare the proportions of clusters with same name and patient but different condition?

Sorry if this is too basic, if it is, could you point me where to find a step by step manual?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do the proportions always sum to 1? (i.e. 100%). E.g. proportion1 0.63 proportion2 0.37 type of thing?

Comment: No, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` is perfect for this sort of data manipulation

Supposing the proportions for each patient/cluster combination sums to 1, then this should do what you're after

```r
library(dplyr)

ggdf %>% 
  select(patient_id, cluster) %>% 
  group_by(patient_id, cluster) %>% 
  summarise(log_proportions=log((proportion/(1-proportion))))
```

Comment: That's great! ...but proportions of same (cluster and patient) and different condition don't sum to 1. How could I do log(proportion for condition "After" / proportion for condition "Base")?

Comment: @Algebio I think in that case it's best to create a column with the values you will provide into the `log()` function, and only then perform the steps above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.